# Submit form that uses Intercooler in Django StaticLiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am trying to write a selenium test for the submission of a form, which uses [intercooler.js](http://intercoolerjs.org/) when it is submitted. The main problem I am having, is that when I navigate to the page, the form has `class="disabled"`, which is not expected behaviour, and I can't submit the form. The relevant part from the `intercooler` docs says:

> By default, intercooler will apply the disabled class to the element
>   that triggers an intercooler request. This can be used to give a
>   visual hint to the user that they should not click or otherwise
>   trigger the request again, and is Bootstrap-friendly.

However, it seems to me that the disabled class is being added to the form element before I actually submit the form, and as I understand it should only be added after a request is in-flight.

The form currently looks like this:

```
<form ic-post-to="/dashboard/calculate/2/exports/" ic-select-from-response="#content" ic-target="#content" method="post" ic-src="/dashboard/calculate/2/exports/" ic-verb="POST" ic-trigger-on="default" ic-deps="ignore" class="disabled">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
    <input type="submit" name="new" value="New" class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-1" id="submit-id-new">
</form>
```

I have tried adding `explicit` and `implicit` waits so that the entire page will load but the problem is still there.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was waiting in the wrong place. Instead of waiting when the page loads, I should have been waiting after the form was submitted to allow the page content to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Javascript` to click on the button:

```
submit = driver.find_element_by_id("submit-id-new")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
```

Comment: I have tried this before and it didn't work, it should redirect to a new page but it remains on the same page

Comment: Yeah I've actually solved this. It turns out the problem was that I needed to wait after the submit button was pressed, not on page load, as when the form is submitted it only causes a partial update of the page content